# jquery.mmenu animate vertical sub menu when clicked

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I am using the vertical menu setting on mmenu and am wondering if I can animate the display of the secondary list items when the expand/collapse link is clicked? I tried applying CSS transitions but the sub menu just hides and shows. I also removed the CSS that changes the from display:none to display:block and tried to just use opacity.

Any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: can you provide a small demo at all?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working as follows:
Remove this CSS

```
.mm-vertical li.mm-opened > .mm-panel,
li.mm-vertical.mm-opened > .mm-panel {
  display: block; }
```

Add this jQuery:

```
var API = $( '#site-navigation' ).data( 'mmenu' );
API.bind( "openPanel", function( $panel ) 
$panel.slideDown( 'slow' );
});
API.bind( "closePanel", function( $panel ) {
$panel.slideUp( 'slow' );
 });
```